# Is it possible to switch an Aurora RDS instance from serverless to instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Is it possible to switch an Aurora RDS instance from the serverless "role" to the instance role? I don't see any way to edit the "Role" field in AWS.

Answer (score 3):

You can *restore* but you can't *switch roles* or *change db type on the fly*.

You'd need to take a snapshot of your RDS Aurora and restore it, but keep in mind that Aurora Serverless  has its requirements, for example regarding engine version.

- [Engine versions for Aurora Serverless V1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.relnotes.html)
- [Engine versions for Aurora Serverless V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.requirements.html)

And here's [how to restore an Aurora DB Severless from a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.relnotes.html).